# MySQL - select table name if it contains record for list of tables

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am interested in finding the most efficient manner to query the following:

- For a list of table names, return the table name if it contains at least one record that meet the conditions

Essentially, something similar to the following Python code in a single query:

```
dfs = [pd.read_sql('SELECT name FROM {} WHERE a=1 AND b=2'.format(table), engine) for table in tables]

tables = [table for table, df in zip(tables, dfs) if not df.empty]
```

Is this possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` of queries that search each table.

```
(SELECT 'table1' AS table_name
FROM table1
WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT 'table2' AS table_name
FROM table2
WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT 'table3' AS table_name
FROM table3
WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2
LIMIT 1)
...
```

Comment: Given `UNION`, is the `LIMIT 1` strictly necessary, other than perhaps for "early exit" per subquery?

Comment: It prevents it from searching the tables for all the matching rows, which will then be thrown away by the union.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you trust the table names in `tables` not to contain any surprises leading to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you could device something like:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

selects = [f'SELECT :table_{i} FROM {table} WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2'
           for i, table in enumerate(tables)]
stmt = ' UNION '.join(selects)
stmt = text(stmt)
results = engine.execute(
    stmt, {f'table_{i}': table for i, table in enumerate(tables)})
```

or you could use SQLAlchemy constructs to build the same query safely:

```
from sqlalchemy import table, column, union, and_, select, Integer, literal

tbls = [table(name,
              column('a', Integer),
              column('b', Integer)) for name in tables]
stmt = union(*[select([literal(name).label('name')]).
               select_from(tbl).
               where(and_(tbl.c.a == 1, tbl.c.b == 2))
               for tbl, name in zip(tbls, tables)])
results = engine.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: Your assumption is an important one and I have assurances in place to protect against SQL injection, so thanks for addressing that. Your approach is very similar to how I have adapted @Barmar's answer to my specific task.